# Redux saga Firebase callback

Tags: react-native, redux, redux-saga

I am trying register a firebase callback using redux-saga in react-native but I am not able to figure out how (I am new to redux-saga). Below is the code I want to write in redux saga:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user) {
        console.log('user logged')
      }
   });
```

Comment: Questions that ask "please help me" tend to be looking for highly localized guidance, or in some cases, ongoing or private assistance, which is not suited to our Q&A format. It is also rather vague, and is better replaced with a more specific question. Please read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Wrap your firebase call in a promise like so:

```
// firebase.js
export function onAuthStateChanged() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user) {
        resolve(user);
      } else {
        reject(new Error('Ops!'));
      }
    });
  });
}

// in your app
import { onAuthStateChanged } from './firebase';

function * saga() {
  try {
    const user = yield call(onAuthStateChanged);
    // ...
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}
```